# How to integrate new relic with nextjs having prerendered page generated and log all browsers error in new relic

Tags: next.js, newrelic

Using getinitialprops causes nextjs not to generate prerender pages on fly how can we integrate in nextjs with JavaScript and how send all browser logged in error messages and server side logs into new relic

I tried integration using getinitialprops but fails on direct load of page

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying this too with no luck, If I find something I will let you know!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).